# Do the PDC and BDC HAVE to be collocated?

Tags: windows-server-2012

Can we put our PDC in the Cloud and the BDC on site. We are on a ship that due to mission cannot be continuously connected to the mandated offship server, for security purposes.

Comment: There are not PDC and BDC. There are FSMO roles. And it sounds like your ship should probably have its own domain, or at least its own site.

Comment: There are so many strange things about this question. But one of the strange things is that, if you are concerned about military-grade security, putting an Active Directory domain controller "in the cloud" is crazy talk.

Comment: @RyanRies [Not that crazy, anymore...](http://aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/)

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, it's still just as crazy... regardless of how common it is, or who/what government agencies do it.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I'm just a confused Linux admin, after all, and everything I know about AD came from you guys anyway.

Comment: It's possible to put a reasonably secure identity and authentication source in a cloud like AWS, Azure, etc.... but, it's definitely not just exposing a bare AD domain controller to the internet.

Comment: Guys... he's not talking about "The Cloud" he's talking about a WAN Cloud across a SATCOM link to NIPRNet or some other protected enclave.

Answer (score 1):

Sandy,

The PDC is a role for a server, it controls numerous things including clock sync on all the workstations.

What effects are you trying to accomplish?

If it's redundancy I would recommmend putting all your FSMO roles on board ship, then have another domain controller with no roles back at port (or in the cloud), if something happens you can seize the roles then build a new DC on ship.

It's a good idea to create a new Site in AD (AD Sites and Services) before deploying any DC across a SATCOM link. Sites and Services are created for bandwidth constrained replication.

If you'd like to follow up I am in the USMC GAL under the same first.last (assuming you are in the US Navy)

Comment: `The PDC is a role for a server, it controls numerous things including clock sync on all the workstations.` - That's correct in a roundabout way. All DC's that don't hold the PDC Emulator role will sync their time with the PDC Emulator, while all other domain members will sync their time with their authenticating DC, which is not necessarily the PDC Emulator.

Comment: You are correct sir. But in this case with 2 DC's (one local, one remote) everything would be syncing to the (local) PDC. A 2 DC setup for short tours is very common in the US Military (I just assumed that's what he was talking about). ;-)

Comment: Come to think of it, an RODC might be a good fit for this scenario. Yes? No?

Comment: I ... don't think so, there's no telling what kind of lash-up they have, or if they are in a chid-domain (is the RODC prep at the domain or forest level?). IMO RODCs make a lot of sense in these situations, it just comes down to "Can we still accomplish the mission if everything goes wrong?" And often there isn't enough local expertise to say yea/nay about RODC.